# How to add a fragment to a dynamically created FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I need to create the frame layout and surrounding layout dynamically. With the `FragmentManager` you have to use the layout's identifier to add the fragment.

When creating a layout dynamically, it does not have an identifier.

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);   
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.??????, fragment)
                .commit();
```

Here I struggle. Can I generate an identifier on the fly and assign it with `frameLayout.setId()`? Is there an alternative?

Comment: you could create array of that number of container's ID and pick according to your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one option is to use `frameLayout.setId()`. To get a proper id for this you can define an id in a ids.xml file for example. See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Another option would be to have a single xml layout file with just a FrameLayout having an id, that you then inflate and use the id defined there.

Both methods let you use an `R.id.xxx`

Comment: declaring the id in the ids.xml file is the good way of obtaining a proper id to set to your layout.